# How can I avoid truncated stage matrices in pipeline stage view with parallelly created stages?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

Imagine a simplified Jenkins job pipeline with parallelly created stages as follows:

```
Random random = new Random();
node {
    def distros = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"];
    parallel(distros.indexed().collectEntries { index, distro ->
        [("${distro}") : {
            println("start stage ${index}: ${distro}");
            /// do some time consuming stuff (like locking resources) before stage can be created
            sh("sleep ${Math.abs(random.nextInt()) % 3}");
            stage("Build ${distro}") {
                "${distro}"
            }
        }]
    })
}
```

Despite every build has the same number of stages with identical names among builds, the build stage matrix ([the view you get, when you click on a job](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS//Pipeline-Stage-View-Plugin.html)) eventually will be truncated to the last build only, because the *order* of the stages changed due to the `parallel` call.

A naive approach to 'enforce' an order would be to wait for an increasing amount of time before each stage like this:

```
Random random = new Random();
node {
    def distros = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"];
    parallel(distros.indexed().collectEntries { index, distro ->
        [("${distro}") : {
            println("start stage ${index}: ${distro}");
            /// do some time consuming stuff (like locking resources) before stage can be created
            sh("sleep ${Math.abs(random.nextInt()) % 3}");

            /// enforce order
            sh("sleep ${index * 4");  

            stage("Build ${distro}") {
                "${distro}"
            }
        }]
    })
}
```

but that not only feels creepy but depending on the steps you need to execute before each stage this can be quite time consuming. Actually if you have more than one stage per (here) `distro` you enforce an order by serializing those parallel builds..

Is there a better approach when my goal is just having a complete overview of persisted builds in the stage view (like [here](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS//Pipeline-Stage-View-Plugin.html))?
Can I somehow pre-define the order of stages?